# Slashes in JAX-RS path

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I have a path like this on a resource class:

```
@Path("/search/{searchKey}/{searchValue: .*}")
```

Containing a method annotated with the following:

```
@Path("details")
```

And another method having no path annotation.

How do I make sure that requests to the following url :

```
baseurl.com/search/key/value1/value2/value3/details
```

are getting correctly routed to the "details" endpoint while requests in the following format:

```
baseurl.com/search/key/value1/value2/value3
```

gets routed to the not annotated method?

Comment: Use `@Path("")` ?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to send such values as path parameters?

Comment: Is `value1/value2/value3` always there with 3 different values?